# "require" to a unique ID? Like DI

Tags: node.js, commonjs

In nodejs you do this:

```
var user = require('./models/users');
```

Is there a way to get the dependecies with an id like this:

```
var user = require('userModel');
```

and in a configuration file I should have something like this:

```
{userModel : './models/user.js'}
```

Is there any native way to reference require dependencies without the relative path? using a config file?

Comment: Why not? Just do `var config = require('./config'); var userModel = require(config.userModel);` where `config.json` is `{"userModel" : "./models/user.js"}`

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy it could be an option, but is not a native one. U have first to always do requiere('./config');

Comment: You could always wrap your config as a module, and install it using NPM (i.e., add a package.json). Then you can require it without a path.